# Capture PCI-Express wheh it is connected and than emulate in system

Tags: windows, registry, emulation, pci-e, device-manager

Is there any way to capture device state when it's connected and than emulate it in Windows? 
I bought some PCI Express devices that need to be present in slots to make software working. But I have only one slot and software not fully works, searching for another 2 cards in slots.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware dongle for licensing?

The answer is no, this isn't possible if the dongle designers had any clue whatsoever about security (using nonce to protect against replay attacks, using asymmetric encryption to produce authentication codes without disclosing the private key).

You might have better luck with a bus extender (bridge chip).  For example [here is one](http://www.plxtech.com/download/file/2070) that turns a PCIe device into a USB peripheral.  Whether the software can still talk to it is anyone's guess, I should think that if the bridge identifies itself to Windows as a PCIe bus then it would.  There are also plenty of PCIe-PCIe bridges that would take your single internal PCIe slot and give you multiple PCIe slots in an external chassis.